# Angular 4 Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, bootstrap-4

I have a fresh created Angular 4 CLI app. After running this:

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta jquery popper.js --save
```

and editing .angular-cli.json like this:

```
"styles": [
  "styles.css",
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
  "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
],
```

I still have an issue in Chrome Console:

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js (https://popper.js.org)
    at eval (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:6:17548)
    at eval (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:6:23163)
    at eval (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:6:50902)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:9)
    at Object.../../../../script-loader/index.js!../../../../bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js (bootstrap.min.js?f885:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap a2f1d85ef068872b0530:54)
    at Object.2 (scripts.bundle.js:66)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap a2f1d85ef068872b0530:54)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap a2f1d85ef068872b0530:25)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You wouldn't have this problem with native Angular directives like https://ng-bootstrap.github.io ....

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Include `popper.js` before `bootstrap.js`:

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
  "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
],
```

Comment: Ensure that you add the version of popper.min.js  in the ./dist/umd folder.  This version ./dist/popper.min.js will cause issues with jquery.

Comment: What about `declare const $: any;` - is here any way to avoid this and have a result?

Comment: @DeveloperWonk How do you know that the popper.js in "umd" folder is the correct one?

Comment: @DeveloperWonk Popper.js is currently shipped with 3 targets in mind: UMD, ESM and ESNext.

UMD - Universal Module Definition: AMD, RequireJS and globals;
ESM - ES Modules: For webpack/Rollup or browser supporting the spec;
ESNext: Available in dist/, can be used with webpack and babel-preset-env;

Comment: i'm a bit confused, don't you need to install typings for jquery/popper/bootstrap?

Comment: Is there any reason to include the *.min.js version of the files? Won't Webpack minify the files when bundling them anyway?

Comment: This solved a problem I was having with Bootstrap 4.2.1 dropdown, where the menu items were not being shown. Installing popper and jquery, then including these script dependencies worked for me.

Comment: Please add a semicolon at the end of the second line

Comment: Works perfectly on Angular 8

Answer (score 20):

> For Angular 7

npm install bootstrap jquery popper.js --save

```
       "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
          "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        ],
```

Answer (score 15):

Was same issue, when I updated app to 8 version of Angular. As solution can use bootstrap bundle minified js file instead bootstrap.min.js. Bootstrap bundle included popper.js already. Need to fix angular.json (`scripts` array in `build` section), in final will be something like this:

```
"scripts": [
    "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
],
```

For this solution `popper.js` is not needed in project. Can remove this module:

```
npm uninstall popper.js
```

just in case, jquery needed :)

Hope, help you

Comment: If I do this with Angular 8 I get an error "can't resolve popper.js"

Comment: It works for me. As I see at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/contents/#js-files popper.js included in bundle

Comment: It works for me as well, I confirm. You can use jquery.slim.min.js, it works!

Comment: Only this worked for me. Installing and including `popper.min.js` before or after `bootstrap.min.js` didn't seem to work.

Comment: Thanks Denis Anisimov, it works for me =D

Answer (score 7):

> Form Angular 8 to 13

npm install bootstrap jquery popper.js --save

```
     "styles": [
      "src/styles.scss",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    ],
    "scripts": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
      "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

The new `https://www.npmjs.com/package/@popperjs/core` doesnt work with bootstrap 5.

it still requires the old `https://www.npmjs.com/package/popper.js?ref=vanillalist` **deprecated** package.

tried in angular 13, it doesnt work, so have to fall back.

Answer (score 0):

> Angular with Bootstrap 5+ Since this version jQuery has been removed

*npm i bootstrap popper.js**

```
 "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ],
 "scripts": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
          "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        ],
```